# Help With Finding A Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I came up to the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 1& 3& -4\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I know that $Im(T)=rank(A)=1$ and $Ker(T)=Null(A)=3$

How can I find the nullspace basis (if I know that I am looking for 3 vectors)?

Comment: A matrix has a variety of associated subspaces: rowspace, columnspace, nullspace.  Which of these do you seek a basis for?

Comment: @vadim123 sorry you are right, I am looking for the nullspace

Comment: **Hint.** Since you know the dimension of the null space is 3, if you find 3 linearly independent vectors that all map to 0, that will be a basis. One strategy would be to decide that the _second_ component of each vector will be nonzero and come up with three different ways to make the image $0$...

Comment: @HenningMakholm so I get $3x+3y-4z=1$ maybe I am very tired but I cant see how it is easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find three vectors $(a,b,c,d)$ that all satisfy $3a+b+3c-4d=0$.  You need to be a tiny bit careful that the three you choose are not dependent.

Many solutions exist, such as $$\{(-1,3,0,0),(0,-3,1,0),(0,4,0,1)\}$$

These are not dependent, because only the first one has anything in the 1st coordinate, only the second has anything in the third coordinate, and only the third has anything in the fourth coordinate.

Comment: So I choose one variable each time and all the other place them with zeros?

Comment: That's one way, yes.

Comment: but then I get all zeros, maybe I need to choose 2 variables and those how left to choose zero for them?
For example to leave the last one and to put one of (0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0) each time

Comment: The simplest way to get vadim123's answer is to note that [tex]\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 3 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \\ u\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 3x+ y+ 3z- 4z \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}[/tex]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get vadim123's answer is to note that $$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 3 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \\ u\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 3x+ y+ 3z- 4u \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$  That is the vector $0$ if and only if $$3x+ y+ 3z- 4u= 0$$ or $$y= 4u- 3x- 3z.$$  So a general vector in the null space would be $$(x, y, z, u)= (x, 4u- 3x- 3z, z, u)= (x, -3x, 0, 0)+ (0, -3z, z, 0)+ (0, 4u, 0, u)= x(1, -3, 0, 0)+ z(0, -3, 1, 0)+ u(0, 4, 0, 1).$$

Comment: but you got: (1, -3, 0, 0) and vadim got (−1,3,0,0)

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts need heavy editing